# Websphere Liberty running on Docker with Open JDK 11

Tags: docker, websphere-liberty, java-11

I'm looking for some guidance on how to use Websphere Liberty (19.0.0.4) with Open JDK 11 on Docker containers.
The Liberty images hosted on Dockerhub use IBM JDK 8.
Does anyone know what is the best practice to build an image which utilises Liberty and a different JDK to the default?

Answer (score 2):

*[Updated Jun 2019]* We now have official docker images for [OpenLiberty](https://hub.docker.com/_/open-liberty) on Java 11 (and 12).

Any image with `-java11-` in the label uses OpenJDK 11 w/ Eclipse OpenJ9 for the VM.

Comment: Thanks Andy, do you have an estimate as to when this might be?

Comment: can't say for certain, but based on the pace of the linked github issue I would guess 2-3 weeks

Comment: Hi Andy, any further news on this topic? Are the official OpenJDK 11 images available yet?

Comment: yes, we now have official Java 11 images on docker hub. I've updated my answer with links

Comment: I'm not seeing any -java11-  tags on Docker Hub for Websphere Liberty. Am I missing something? I can see the Dockerfile.java11 on Github but I was assuming there would be dedicated tags?

Comment: @Lee you are correct, we don't have the official Websphere Liberty images on java 11 yet. Need to sort through some legal work still -- will aim to get these out soon